# change the h3 subtitles of the wordpress gallery shortcode

Tags: images, shortcode, gallery

When I create an image gallery in a WordPress entry with shortcode [gallery] and put their titles on them, they appear in H3

Any way to change them to be on h4? Example of a gallery image created in WordPress:

```
<figure class="gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
            <a href="https://huerto.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/cultivo-de-ajo-en-tobo.jpg"><img width="150" height="150" src="https:/huerto.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/cultivo-de-ajo-en-tobo-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="cultivo de ajo en tobo"></a>
            </div><figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-5458"><h3 id="Cultivo_de_ajo_en_tobo">Cultivo de ajo en tobo</h3><p>cultivo de ajo en tobo</p></figcaption></figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of the issue. If it is simply the text is too large, try using CSS to scale the font size.

```
.gallery-item h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: hi, what i want is to change from h3 to h4

Comment: Have you tried using `captiontag="h4"` inside your shortcode?